# H2 database CREATE TABLE with constraint

Tags: sql, h2

I have two SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE legs(legid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                  playerid1 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES players(playerid),
                  playerid2 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES players(playerid),
                  added TIMESTAMP AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE legs ADD CONSTRAINT distinct_players CHECK(playerid1 <> playerid2);
```

I am 99% sure I should be able to condense them into one, i.e:

```
CREATE TABLE table(...
                   playerid2 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES players(playerid) CHECK(playerid1 <> playerid2),
                   ...);
```

However, I am consistently getting a syntax error.  AFAIK, this is where the constraint should be.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE legs(legid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                  playerid1 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES players(playerid),
                  playerid2 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES players(playerid),
                  added TIMESTAMP AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                  CHECK (playerid1 <> playerid2));
```

Comment: The check constraints have to all be at the bottom of the table and cannot be intermixed with the columns, as CHECK constraints can be intermixed in PostgreSQL.